# extract lines from a text file, pattern will be identified by parsing the file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, text

One needs to extract lines from a txt file, to other files, based on the following scenario:

The first pattern to match against, will be always the line that starts with the word `identifier`, then the second pattern, will be the first line, that starts with `000`:

in the below example, it will be

```
000: thislineneedstobeextracted
```

after we have written the output to the first file, we move to extract the lines that start with the word `identifier`, and the lines that start again with `000`: but this time, for the second unique occurrence found in the file, in our example,

```
000: alsothislineneedstobeextracted
```

and the output will be written to the second file, etc.

sample input

```
identifier 767  
linetobeignored  
anotherlinetobeignored  
000: thislineneedstobeextracted  
000: alsothislineneedstobeextracted  
blankline  
identifier 7686    
linetobeignored  
anotherlinetobeignored  
000: thislineneedstobeextracted  
000: alsothislineneedstobeextracted  
000: ayetanotherlineneedstobeextracted
```

sample output file1.txt:

```
000: thislineneedstobeextracted  
identifier 767  
identifier 7686
```

sample output file2.txt:

```
000: alsothislineneedstobeextracted  
identifier 767  
identifier 7686
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: Did you do anything yourself or do you expect us to do your homework?

Answer (score 0):

Try with **awk**

```
awk '
    /^id/{
        if(line[1]){
            for(n in line)print line[n],i,$0 >> "file"n".txt"
            delete(line)
            }
        c=0
        i=$0
        }
    /^000:/{
        line[++c]=$0
        }
    END{
        if(line[1]){
            for(n in line)print line[n],i,$0 >> "file"n".txt"
        }
    ' OFS=\\n txt.file
```